# Make Gmail ask for "from" address with multiple inbox account

Tags: gmail

I use my personal Gmail domain account to consolidate four (4) other accounts, two (2) of them work accounts.

I know there is a way to select the "From" address when composing a new mail, but how do I  make Gmail ask or prompt me so I don't ever accidentally leave the wrong address set?

Answer (score 2):

No, but I believe when you reply to a message it sets the To: field accordingly.

This is done when the
"*Reply from the same address the message was sent to*"
is checked in Settings > Accounts and Import