# Always show from address in GMail's compose view

Tags: gmail

I have several "from" addresses added to my GMail account. In the new compose view, the from address is visible and changeable as long as "to" is focused, but is collapsed when subject or the message body is focused. I want the "from" address to always be visible so I can take a glance at it to quickly make sure that I will send send the e-mail using the right address. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [Make Gmail ask for "from" address with multiple inbox account](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14806)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve the question, and I also don't believe my question is a dupe of that.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was a duplicate. Only that it was related.

Comment: Actually neither was I suggesting that you were suggesting it. I was just pointing it out in case someone else would see it that way and consider reporting the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can show from address in GMail's compose view by switching to the old Gmail interface using the browser extension [Retro Compose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk/) (Chrome), [Old Compose](http://oldcompose.com/) (Chrome+Firefox), or [Fix Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-compose-for-gmail%C2%AE-to/hpoidnelefpoofhdioielagfklahfcjg/):

[image]